# Cannot Run application from shared path

Tags: c#-4.0

I can run application from local machine everything is working fine, but when I share and run same on shared folder it is giving an nhibernate exception [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jabzo.png)

That IsCrossRefInformed code is not committed to the shared folder It is in my local machine

Comment: Are you sure that the code (and configuration) in a share folder is exactly the same as the one on a local machine?

Comment: yes thanks it got solved somehow on refreshing......